# Add category page doesn't properly load

Tags: admin, category

When I try to add a new category page it starts to load and then seems to reload the whole window inside the where the category list should be. The window starts to flicker, reloading over and over with the loading gif present. Not sure what to do as I am new to Magento and just trying to stand it up in a dev environment.

[Category Page http://imageshack.com/a/img829/3136/9r1g.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img829/3136/9r1g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try installing version 1.9 that the notification at the top is telling you about to see if that solves the issue?

However if you have to be on the current version that you have installed try re-uplaoding the Magento installation files for that version and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: That message was telling me about 1.8, I had already installed 1.9

Re-copying the files appeared to fix the problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

Man this took ages to figure out...the other answers we're red herrings at least for me.

Basically my server was setup so that it was not reading query strings in the url and the $_GET Array was empty.  This means the `?isAjax` query in the controller for that page was not being recognised and it started acting strange.

For me it was in my nginx configuration, but the solution will be different for each setup.